# Postgresql, sql command, join table with similar string, only string "OM:" is at the begin

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I wanna join table.

```
left join
c_store on o_order.customer_note = c_store.store_code
```

String in field is almost same, just contains "OM:" on start of field, for example, field from o_order.customer_note is

```
OM:4008
```

and from c_store.store_code is

```
4008
```

Is possible to join table c_store.store_code based on remove (or replace ) from every field in o_order.customer_note?

I tried

```
c_store on replace(o_order.customer_note, '', 'OM:') = c_store.store_code
```

but no success. I think, this is only for rename column name, right? Sorry for this question, I am new in this.

Thanks.

Comment: replace method write wrong, should be `replace(o_order.customer_note,'OM:', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string concatenation in your join condition:

```
SELECT ...
FROM o_order o
LEFT JOIN c_store c
    ON o.customer_note = 'OM:' || c.store_code::text;
```

But not that while the above logic might fix your query in the short term, in the long term the better fix would be to have proper join columns setup in your database.  That is, it is desirable to be able to do joins on equality alone.  This would let Postgres use an index, if it exists.